# Bloated Pimple Container - Is this normal?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, pimple

So I've just integrated Pimple into a project and the situation I'm in now is that I have a file at:

```
/application/config/pimple.php
```

With 400+ of these in it:

```
/* Instantiate new Class */
$this->container['Some_class'] = $this->container->factory(function ($c) 
{
    require_once "application/classes/some/class.php";
    return new Class();
});
```

My question is: Is this the norm? Should I be concerned about this? Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be concerned about this?

Well, no. You *can* work with that. The framework [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) uses Pimple as service container as well. But Pimple is a *small* dependency injection container. It is very good for small projects, but if your container grows up, you might want something different. If you look for something "better", look for the [DependencyInjection's](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html) component. With that you can describe your DIC behaviour in a configuration file, example:

```
parameters:
    # ...
    mailer.transport: sendmail

services:
    mailer:
        class:     Mailer
        arguments: ["%mailer.transport%"]
    newsletter_manager:
        class:     NewsletterManager
        calls:
            - [setMailer, ["@mailer"]]
```

*Note*: it is advisable to register an autoloader instead of include the class manually.